# How to do timeIntervalSinceNow in Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift3, nstimeinterval

I was making a notification and watching a tutorial on it and when I typed in:

```
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
```

it says

> Argument labels '(timeIntervalSinceNow:)' do not match any available
>   overloads

How do I fix this? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer = Timer()
    var time = 10
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("Notification")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func notification() {
        time -= 1
        if time <= 0 {
            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertAction = "Call"
            notification.alertBody = "You have a call right now"
            notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func pushNotification(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let AlertView = UIAlertController(title: "Time for your call!", message: "Press go to continue", preferredStyle:  .alert)
        AlertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(AlertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: But then it says I have to make it `notification.fireDate = NSDate() as Date` and then it doesn't work

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't get an error when I do what you said but I get Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: @LeoDabus where should I put that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123825/discussion-between-krish-mehra-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: that definitely works but now I don't get a notification when I leave the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the fire date to be now, it's just:

```
notification.fireDate = Date()
```

---

As Leo noted elsewhere, the selector is incorrect. It should be:

```
weak var timer: Timer?
var time = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func handleTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
    time -= 1

    if time <= 0 {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()

        notification.alertAction = "Call"
        notification.alertBody = "You have a call right now"
        notification.fireDate = Date()

        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

You then asked:

> that definitely works but now I don't get a notification when I leave the app

You don't get the notification when you leave your app, because the `Timer` doesn't continue to fire when the app isn't running. It's better to eliminate the timer altogether and just immediately schedule the local notification for the desired time. For example, to schedule a local notification to fire in 10 seconds:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scheduleLocalNotification(delay: 10)
}

func scheduleLocalNotification(delay: TimeInterval) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    notification.alertAction = "Call"
    notification.alertBody = "You have a call right now"
    notification.fireDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(delay)

    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus already said that but when I type that in I get a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: Yes, that's because your selector is wrong, as Leo pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
let minute:TimeInterval = 11.0 * 60.0;
Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: minute);
```

for +11 minutes to now.